# How to make internal storage writable in android?

Tags: android, permissions, storage, internal, writable

I have Huawei Ascend Y530 phone with android 4.3 and now I can't neither read nor write from/to internal storage. At first time it was working fine after some time it just happened. Please help me how to make my internal storage writable. Tried a command restorecon -v -R /media/data on Terminal Emulator, but it kept saying Could not get context of /data/media: Operation not suppored on transport endpoint. Please help

Comment: What do you mean by internal storage? The built in 'external storage' ? The private storage for apps?

Comment: Hello JonasCz,  I mean the built in storage, not private storage, the one files received via bluetooth resides in or you can say sdcard0.

Comment: That's wired, maybe go into setting > storage and format it?

Comment: Is your question about programming? If no,  then it is offtopic.

Comment: Yes you can say so, I have tried a command chown system /storage/sdcard0 on terminal and gave an error operation not permitted. I have also tried chmod 777 /storage/sdcard0 and nothing. I was root.